# How to select rows using key board in data grid in flex

Tags: apache-flex

HI,

I need to select rows using key board up and down arrow buttons in the flex data grid.Please give the solution.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

You can move between cells and rows using keyboard navigation.  I'm not sure how that reflects in the selectedIndices / selectedItems properties, though.

You may be able to work something out by listening to the keyPress events; I'd probably start with keyUp: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:keyUp